# why and how to fix the HTTP/1.1 406 Not Accept issue

Tags: groovy, pipeline

I have a pipeline snippet in file `java.jenkinsfile` to invoke remote gitlab to merge request.
This is groovy pipeline snippet which very simple

```
#!groovy

@Library('jenkinslib@main') _
def gitlab = new org.devops.gitlab()

gitlab.AcceptMr(projectId,mergeId)
```

another, I've defined that function at file `gitlab.groovy` in `jenkinslib` which is a shared library.

snippet in file `gitlab.groovy`

```
def HttpReq(reqType,reqUrl,reqBody){
    def gitServer = "http://10.4.7.101:8929/api/v4"
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'gitlab-token', variable: 'gitlabToken')]) {
        result = httpRequest customHeaders: [[maskValue: true, name: 'PRIVATE-TOKEN', value: "${gitlabToken}"]],
                    httpMode: reqType,
                    contentType: "APPLICATION_JSON",
                    consoleLogResponseBody: true,
                    ignoreSslErrors: true,
                    requestBody: reqBody,
                    url: "${gitServer}/${reqUrl}"
                    //quiet: true
    }
    return result
}

def AcceptMr(projectId,mergeId){
    def apiUrl = "projects/${projectId}/merge_requests/${mergeId}/merge"
    HttpReq('PUT',apiUrl,'')
}
```

then, I did run the pipeline in Jenkins, but shown issue to me in pipeline console output like

```
[Pipeline] httpRequest
Warning: A secret was passed to "httpRequest" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [gitlabToken]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
HttpMethod: PUT
URL: http://10.4.7.101:8929/api/v4/projects/7/merge_requests/6/merge
Content-Type: application/json
PRIVATE-TOKEN: *****
Sending request to url: http://10.4.7.101:8929/api/v4/projects/7/merge_requests/6/merge
Response Code: HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Response: 
{"message":"Branch cannot be merged"}
```

That code `HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable` seem like told me my request content format is incorrect. but that function `AcceptMr` quite simple to only post a merge request to gitlab.

How to fix that??
please help.

thanks very much.

Comment: shouldnt the content-type be `application/json`?

Comment: hi @tim_yates, thank you for reply, then what's the content is correct in content-type??

Comment: hi @tim_yates pipeline snippet of `content-type` which could [refer](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) I tried to put every one in it but      got failure